# ROS2 port of ORB SLAM3. Can copy libDoW2.so and libg2o.so using Cmake but getting error while loading shared libraries: libpango_vars.so

Tags: cmake, ros-humble, target-link-libraries

Ubuntu 22.04, ROS2 Humble

Hi,

To port my research project to ROS2, I have been trying to make a native ROS2 implementation of ORB SLAM3 following the ROS1 implementation done by thien94 in
`https://github.com/thien94/orb_slam3_ros/blob/master/`.

As far I have understood, the ROS 1 implementation integrates ORB-SLAM3 as a shared library along with the executable node.

My project structure looks like the following

[image]

This Cmake configuration allows me to build the node and orb slam3 as a shared library

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(orb_slam3_ros2)

set(ENV{PYTHONPATH} "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/") # Must be set to match your installation

# Must use C++17 to make it compatible with rclcpp
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -O3")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -O3")

# Check C++17 support
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++17" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX17)

if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX17)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
  add_definitions(-DCOMPILEDWITHC17)
  message(STATUS "Using flag -std=c++17.")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++17 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()

LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules)

# LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/Thirdparty/g2o/cmake_modules)

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(custom_msg_interface REQUIRED)
find_package(cv_bridge REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV 4.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 3.3.0 REQUIRED) # Matched with Sophus
find_package(Pangolin REQUIRED)
#message("Pangolin libraries: ${Pangolin_LIBRARIES}")
find_package(image_transport REQUIRED)
#find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

# Doesn't work, needs to work with very old version as discussed here https://github.com/lrse/sptam/issues/49
# find_package(G2O REQUIRED)
# if(NOT G2O_FOUND)
#    message(FATAL_ERROR "G2O not found.")
# endif()

# Boost doesn't work
# set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
# set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
# set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
# find_package(Boost 1.83.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system serialization)
# find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

# -------------------------- ORB SLAM3 library build includes


include_directories(include) # This package include

# Library's includes
include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/include
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/include/CameraModels
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/Thirdparty
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/Thirdparty/Sophus
  ${ament_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

include_directories(SYSTEM
  ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Pangolin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

set(THIS_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DEPENDS
  rclcpp
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  custom_msg_interface
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  OpenCV
  Eigen3
  Pangolin
)

# Redundant?
# include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/Thirdparty/DBoW2/CMakeLists.txt)
# include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/Thirdparty/g2o/CMakeLists.txt)
# set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/lib)

# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
add_library(orb_slam3_ros2 SHARED
  orb_slam3/src/System.cc
  orb_slam3/src/Tracking.cc
  orb_slam3/src/LocalMapping.cc
  orb_slam3/src/LoopClosing.cc
  orb_slam3/src/ORBextractor.cc
  orb_slam3/src/ORBmatcher.cc
  orb_slam3/src/FrameDrawer.cc
  orb_slam3/src/Converter.cc
  orb_slam3/src/MapPoint.cc
  orb_slam3/src/KeyFrame.cc
  orb_slam3/src/Atlas.cc
  orb_slam3/src/Map.cc
  orb_slam3/src/MapDrawer.cc
  orb_slam3/src/Optimizer.cc
  orb_slam3/src/Frame.cc
  orb_slam3/src/KeyFrameDatabase.cc
  orb_slam3/src/Sim3Solver.cc
  orb_slam3/src/Viewer.cc
  orb_slam3/src/ImuTypes.cc
  orb_slam3/src/G2oTypes.cc
  orb_slam3/src/CameraModels/Pinhole.cpp
  orb_slam3/src/CameraModels/KannalaBrandt8.cpp
  orb_slam3/src/OptimizableTypes.cpp
  orb_slam3/src/MLPnPsolver.cpp
  orb_slam3/src/GeometricTools.cc
  orb_slam3/src/TwoViewReconstruction.cc
  orb_slam3/src/Config.cc
  orb_slam3/src/Settings.cc
  orb_slam3/src/SystemUtils.cc
  orb_slam3/include/System.h
  orb_slam3/include/Tracking.h
  orb_slam3/include/LocalMapping.h
  orb_slam3/include/LoopClosing.h
  orb_slam3/include/ORBextractor.h
  orb_slam3/include/ORBmatcher.h
  orb_slam3/include/FrameDrawer.h
  orb_slam3/include/Converter.h
  orb_slam3/include/MapPoint.h
  orb_slam3/include/KeyFrame.h
  orb_slam3/include/Atlas.h
  orb_slam3/include/Map.h
  orb_slam3/include/MapDrawer.h
  orb_slam3/include/Optimizer.h
  orb_slam3/include/Frame.h
  orb_slam3/include/KeyFrameDatabase.h
  orb_slam3/include/Sim3Solver.h
  orb_slam3/include/Viewer.h
  orb_slam3/include/ImuTypes.h
  orb_slam3/include/G2oTypes.h
  orb_slam3/include/CameraModels/GeometricCamera.h
  orb_slam3/include/CameraModels/Pinhole.h
  orb_slam3/include/CameraModels/KannalaBrandt8.h
  orb_slam3/include/OptimizableTypes.h
  orb_slam3/include/MLPnPsolver.h
  orb_slam3/include/GeometricTools.h
  orb_slam3/include/TwoViewReconstruction.h
  orb_slam3/include/SerializationUtils.h
  orb_slam3/include/Config.h
  orb_slam3/include/Settings.h
  orb_slam3/include/SystemUtils.h
  
  
)

set_target_properties(orb_slam3_ros2 PROPERTIES VERSION "${orb_slam3_ros2_VERSION}")
#set_target_properties(orb_slam3_ros2 PROPERTIES PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

ament_target_dependencies(orb_slam3_ros2
  ${THIS_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DEPENDS}
)

# Works do not delete
target_link_libraries(orb_slam3_ros2
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
  ${EIGEN3_LIBS}
  ${Pangolin_LIBRARIES}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/Thirdparty/DBoW2/lib/libDBoW2.so
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/Thirdparty/g2o/lib/libg2o.so
  -lboost_system
  -lboost_serialization
  -lcrypto 
)


# Find your .so files (replace lib1.so and lib2.so with your actual file names)
set(DBoW2_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/Thirdparty/DBoW2/lib/libDBoW2.so")
set(g2o_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/orb_slam3/Thirdparty/g2o/lib/libg2o.so")

# Install .so files to the lib directory in the install space
install(FILES ${DBoW2_PATH} DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${g2o_PATH} DESTINATION lib)



# --------------------------------------- CPP node ------------------------------------------

# Add executable
add_executable(agent0
  src/agent0.cpp
  src/robot_slam.cpp
)
#ament_target_dependencies(agent0 vslam_lib rclcpp std_msgs sensor_msgs custom_msg_interface cv_bridge Pangolin Eigen3 image_transport OpenCV)
#ament_target_dependencies(agent0 rclcpp std_msgs sensor_msgs custom_msg_interface cv_bridge Pangolin Eigen3 image_transport OpenCV)

ament_target_dependencies(agent0
  PUBLIC ${THIS_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DEPENDS}
)

target_link_libraries(agent0
  PUBLIC
  orb_slam3_ros2
)

# Install the library
install(
  TARGETS orb_slam3_ros2
  EXPORT orb_slam3_ros2Targets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include/orb_slam3_ros2
)

# install(
#   TARGETS orb_slam3_ros2
#   EXPORT export_orb_slam3_ros2
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION lib/orb_slam3_ros2
#   INCLUDES DESTINATION include/orb_slam3_ros2
# )

# Install this executable
install(TARGETS agent0
  DESTINATION lib/orb_slam3_ros2
)

# This works
install (DIRECTORY include/ 
        DESTINATION include/orb_slam3_ros2
)

ament_export_include_directories(include)     # <-- superfluous?
ament_export_libraries(rb_slam3_ros2Targets)             # <-- superfluous?
ament_export_targets(orb_slam3_ros2Targets HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)
```

With a `colcon build --packages-select orb_slam3_ros2` it builds successfully. But when I invoke this command

```
ros2 run orb_slam3_ros2 agent0 --ros-args -p agent_name:=robot0
```

I am getting this error

```
/home/tigerwife/ros2_ws/install/orb_slam3_ros2/lib/orb_slam3_ros2/agent0: error while loading shared libraries: libpango_vars.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I followed the official tutorial in `https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin` and installed Pangolin in `home/pangolin/Pangolin`. My ROS workspace is here `home/ros2_ws`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

With best
@Mechazo11

Comment: I have made cmake copy the .so files from the two Thirdparty projects into the install directory and now this problem has been resolved. But it seems, the package cannot find Pangolin even though find_package(Pangolin REQUIRED) finds it just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by installing Pangolin globally in my system. This approach along with adding a macro in `.bashrc` ensures the .so files are found by Cmake during run time from `/usr/local/lib` folder.

The steps to installing Pangolin globally are as follows

1. git clone and change directory into the downloaded folder using the following instructions in `https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin`
2. Install recommended software `./scripts/install_prerequisites.sh --dry-run recommended`
3. Install recommended dependencies `./scripts/install_prerequisites.sh recommended`
4. `cmake -B build` create a build directory and configure using Cmake
5. `cmake --build build -j4` build using 4 parallel processors
6. `sudo cmake --install build` install pangolin system-wide with elevated privileges
7. Optional: test Pangolin is installed correctly by running one of the provided examples

8a. In a terminal, check if `/usr/lib/local` is added to Dynamic library path using `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

8b. Add `/usr/lib/local` and update ldconfig as follows

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/local
sudo ldconfig
```

9. Open .bashrc file and then add the following lines at the very of the file

```
if [[ ":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:" != *":/usr/local/lib:"* ]]; then
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi
```

10. source the .bashrc file to solve the above problem
    `source ~/.bashrc`

With best,
@mechazo11